# php string manipulation

Tags: php, string, parsing, url

i have this string:

```
http://localhost/migo2/photo.php?id=68&a_id=83&p_id=349&type=1#p_id=302
```

and i would like to get the value of type (which is 1 obviously)

i do a

```
parse_str("http://localhost/migo2/photo.php?id=68&a_id=83&p_id=349&type=1#p_id=302");
```

and get

```
echo $type; -> 1#p_id=302
```

so i was thinking if i had a function that removed everything on the right side of # and the # itself i think i get what i want. Is this a bad way of doing it?

Comment: explode the string by `?` and then by `#` would be the quickest solution.

Comment: PHP has built-in functions for getting the query string out of the URL, then parsing the query string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to parse the URL into components, then call [`parse_str`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) only on the query string.

```
$str = "http://localhost/migo2/photo.php?id=68&a_id=83&p_id=349&type=1#p_id=302";
$parts = parse_url($str);
parse_str($parts['query'], $arr);
echo $arr['type'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [parse-url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function and specify PHP_URL_QUERY. That will give you the query part first.

This is the main result when searching for PHP Parse Url btw, which is basically your question. ;)